# Как стилизовать чекбоксы в contact form 7?

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form7

Есть форма в попап окне красная кнопка Отправить заявку
Не получается стилизовать чекбоксы 
в Google Chrome не ставиться галочка в чекбоксах
в Firefox работает как исправить?
[Ссылка на сайт](http://papaprint.md/plastikovye-karty/)

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) Это [пример](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/391_checkboxes/demo.html) как работает в Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не важно какой плагин вы используете, единственный момент, какая структура HTML-разметки, такая:

```
<label>
 <input type='checkbox'/>
 <span>чекбокс 1</span>
</label>
```

или такая:

```
<input type="checkbox"/ id="checkbox_1">
<label for='checkbox_1'>Чекбокс 2</label>
```

Если не ошибаюсь в CF7 можно прикручивать пользовательские классы к полям формы.

Для первого варианта могу предложить свой вариант стилизации чекбокса.
Верстка кросбраузерная, за исключением, разве что, IE8-

```css
.checkbox {
 display: block;
}
.checkbox__choice {
 margin: 0 3px 0 0;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
}
.checkbox__label {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 0 0 25px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #000;
 font-size: .875rem;
    opacity: .8;
}
.checkbox__choice {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox__label::before {
    border: 4px solid #52afec;
    border-radius: 50%;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 left: 0;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
.checkbox__choice:checked + .checkbox__label::before {
    background-color: #52afec;
}
.checkbox__choice:checked + .checkbox__label {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__choice" name="feedback_agreement">
  <span class="checkbox__label">Я принимаю условия <a class="link" href="/user_agreement/" target="_blank">пользовательского соглашения</a> и даю своё согласие на обработку моих персональных данных, в соответствии с Федеральным законом от 27.07.2006 года №152-ФЗ "О персональных данных", на условиях и для целей, определенных <a class="link" href="/privacy_policy/" target="_blank">Политикой конфиденциальности</a>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Если честно, уже не актуально, но благодарю за ответ)